# Is it possible to see the function description windows that pop up in IDLE when you use a function in any other IDEs?

Tags: python, ide

I'm not really sure how to phrase this. When you use a function and an open parenthesis in IDLE a little yellow window pops up and contains the function documentation. For example, if you type int( in IDLE and wait, the window will say "() int(x = 0) -> int or long" which is the function description. Are there any other IDEs that support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using pycharm or visual studios community edition.